# Remover string depois de "ponto" em um número

Tags: javascript

Tenho em uma variável no javascript o valor:

```
<script>
var valor1 = "123.33";
</script>
```

Gostaria de remover o .33, deixar apenas o 123. Levando em consideração que esse valor é variável, pode ser 1233.30, 1001.44, enfim...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Já tem pronto algo testado que é o [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
console.log(parseInt("123.33"));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/ParseInt.js).

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "123.33";
var res = str.split(".");

alert(res[0]);
```

res[0] = 123